# wavetable parameters for audiokit

Tags: ios, waveform, audiokit

AudioKit is amazing and lets you start some oscillators and vary their frequency on-the-fly.  Now I want to change the shape of the waveforms so that I can create custom timbres for my oscillators.

There are four standard types, actually five that AudioKit supports:

```
- sine
- triangle (good sine approximate)
- square wave
- sawtooth
- reverse sawtooth wave
```

All of them sound differently, but it would be really great if I could change the type of Waveform by using the built-in waveTable support.

http://audiokit.io/docs/Structs/AKTable.html#/s:vV8AudioKit7AKTable6valuesGSaSf_ Mentions the **AKMorphingOscillator** which is like a miracle class that can change waveForms for the oscillator.  The defaults all work, but I am really new to populating the AKTable field.

The git page https://github.com/audiokit/AudioKit/blob/master/AudioKit/Common/Internals/AKTable.swift  shows that:

```
/// A table of values accessible as a waveform or lookup mechanism
public struct AKTable {

    // MARK: - Properties

    /// Values stored in the table
    public var values = [Float]()

    /// Number of values stored in the table
    var size = 4096

    /// Type of table
    var type: AKTableType

    // MARK: - Initialization

    /// Initialize and set up the default table 
    ///
    /// - parameter tableType: AKTableType of teh new table
    /// - parameter size: Size of the table (multiple of 2)
    ///
    public init(_ tableType: AKTableType = .Sine, size tableSize: Int = 4096) {
        type = tableType
        size = tableSize
        ....
```

So my question is, can I directly access the **values** array and simply modify it to make new waveforms?  Is there a sensible or idiomatic way to do this?

Danke.

Comment: you should probably ask this question in the github repository issues: https://github.com/audiokit/AudioKit/issues. The developers are generally prompt to help. Cheers.

Comment: @Oleiade thanks for the link and the head's up, friend!

Answer (score 0):

Since AudioKit support is moving off Google Groups to StackOverflow, I'm responding to even older issues here.  Basically tables can be anything you want. They are classes, not tables anymore and there is a playground that shows how to use them and plot them with AKTableView.

Check it out here: http://audiokit.io/playgrounds/Basics/Tables/